# A problem relating to combinatorics/ Permutation|Combination

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

The question is: (I actually may have messed up!)

> Suppose we have $4$ numbers namely : $a,b,c$ and $d$
>
> Now we need to **compare** *two* of these numbers **four at a time**.

For example :

1. $a>b$ | $b>c$ | $c>d$ | $a>d$
2. $a<b$ | $b>c$ | $a>c$ | $b>d$ $\space \space \space \space \space
       ...$[Here $c$ is repeated and there is no specification of $\space \space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space$relation between $a$ and $d$]

> We should also keep in mind that if $a>b$ and $b>c$ then $a \nless c$
>
> So how many such possibilities can happen (two are shown)?

Comment: Is there any limit on numbers?

Comment: @abcz No...the sum should be done based on Variables a,b,c and d (so 4 variables)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edit: I see only now that TravisJ answered an other question than you asked. Here is also the answer to the question you actually asked originally:*

First, there are ${6 \choose 4}$ ways to choose which 4 of the 6 possible equations are given. 12 of those are of the form $a * b | a * c | a * d | b * c $ where * is an element of ${<, =, >}$. The other 3 are similar as $a * b | a * c | b * d | c * d $.

For the first type, we can place all three symbols into the first three equations. That gives 27 possiblities. One of those is $a<b | a < c | a < d$. In this special case all three possibilities are still possible for $b * c$. That is the case when the symbol of both $a*b$ and $a*c$ are the same and not $=$. So for 6 cases. That gives for this situation thus $12 \times (6*3+21)$ possibilities.

In the second case counting which possiblities are allowed is somewhat harder. Though, we can surely choose the first 3 in all 27 ways without contradictions. For example $a < b | a > c | b = d$. In this example we have to choose the last equation as $c< d$ as we have $d=b>a>c$. I think that in 13 out of 27 cases we have no choose in the last equation, but you should check this as I'm not sure (the cases I found are when $d=b$, $a=b=c$, $c<a<b<d$ or $d>b>a>c$). That gives $3 \times (14*3+13)$ possibilities in this case.

So, that gives a total of $3 \times (14*3^4+13*3^3)+12 \times (6*3^4+21*3^3) = 633$ possibilities.

---

From here on, I answer the question on the way that TravisJ intreperted it.

Actually, there are less than TravisJ answer tells as some of the 192 ways are the same. For example: $a = b < c < d$ and $b = a < c < d$ are different, but counted twice in that answer.

The good answer should be $4! + 3! *{4 \choose 2} + 2*3 + 4*2 + 1 = 75$. The reasoning is as follows:

- There are $4!$ ways to order $a,b,c$ and $d$ without using =-signs.
- When there is exactly one =-sign, there are ${4 \choose 2} = 6$ ways to choose which two numbers are equal and then still 3! ways to place all the numbers.
- If there are three variables equal to each other, there are 4 ways to choose which one is not equal to the other three and that variable can be larger or smaller than the others.
- When there are two sets of two variables that are equal to each other, there are three posibilities for which variable is equal to $a$ and that two variables can be larger or smaller than the other two variables.
- Finally there is only one situation in which all variables are equal to all others.